# Longest path in undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

let's say I have an undirected unweighted graph where each edge can be "visited" only once. How can I get the longest path? I've seen something like NP-hard or depth-first search. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

**If there are no cycles** in your graph, you can put -1 weights on each edge and search for the shortest path with the Bellman-Ford algorithm.

If there are cycles, your problem is NP-hard indeed, and you need to proceed differently, with integer programming for example.

**Note.** The shortest path with negative weights equals the longest path. If weights are unitary, and the shortest path is, say -20, then the longest path has length 20.

Comment: But I want longest path

Comment: Yes, but a shortest path with negative weights will give you the longest path!

Comment: Can you tell me why is that so? :-)) Because I'm quite new in graphs and I know Dijkstra algorithm just a little

Comment: More explanation can be found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths . Note that it's just about acyclic graphs. In general your problem is NP-hard

Comment: Pretty sure Dijkstra's doesn't work with negative edge weights; Bellman-Ford has similar complexity and works in acyclic graphs with negative weights.

Comment: You are right, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension of Kuifje's answer. If you want to count how many edges are there on the shortest path between the two vertices, you may want to put weight 1 to every edge. Here's an image to give you an idea. It shows the shortest path between the vertices $A$ and $D$ in red. Clearly the weight of this path is 2 and there are 2 edges on it. It is pretty easy to see that this holds in general.

[image]

In the similar manner, we can also ask what the longest path is, but since we have nice algorithms to find the shortest path, we might want to turn this problem in the shortest path problem. If we construct the graph as above, clearly if the longest path has $k$ edges, the weight of that path will be $k$. But if we want this to be the smallest weight path, we might want to multiply all the edges by -1. Clearly this reverses the relation "is longer path" and hence the longest path in terms of the number of edges will be the shortest path in terms of the weight. Here's the same example below:

[image]

We can see that the path highlighted in red is the longest $A-D$ path in terms of the number of edges (3), however it is the shortest in terms of the weight (-3).

Note that this is not an "easy" problem to solve in general and it is often "impossible" to find an efficient algorithm to obtain such a solution. (assuming $P\neq NP$).